# How to know why a question is downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I've got this question downvoted:

[JPA does not delete database row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365271/jpa-does-not-delete-database-row)

and I don't know why. I mean, it's ok to downvote of course, but how can I know why to avoid make same mistake and post better questions in future? The way the downvote work actually doesn't help author improve his questions, my question seems legit to me of course, so maybe a simple "question downvoted because ..." can point me to the problem.
I think that prompt user to specify reason for downvoting can help improving questions level.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to know.  Voting is anonymous, and voters are not obligated to explain why they downvoted.  Usually the reason is "insufficient prior research" or "your question is under-specified."

Comment: @RobertHarvey or you're being downvotes because someone *doesn't like you*

Comment: I suggested an edit to help with the grammar issues and remove a couple fluff items. Feel free to rollback if you disagree, but I think it may help readability.

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted your edits. 
I apologize for my errors, but not everyone is english speaking, I think downvoting because of grammar, if the question is understandable, it's not fair, and it should be avoided.

Comment: It is supposed to be an English site, so some people may not realize the asker might not be a native speaker and may have issues, if that's why they downvoted. If that _is_ why they downvoted, they'd be better off editing to fix grammar. I write a lot, so grammar flaws sometimes jump out at me. When they do, I offer a fix. Glad you found it helpful.

Comment: Downvotes can be given for any reason; they had a bad day, they don't like you, or your question is bad. I consider it a "flaw".

Answer (score 10):

Here are some possible reasons:

1. You're not using correct English.  Check your spelling, punctuation and capitalization.
2. You're inserting additions to your post in the form of EDITs.  This is how forums work, but not how Stack Overflow works.  The Stack Overflow community expects to see a coherent question, not a history lesson.  Learn and understand the Q&A format.
3. In general, questions like yours are often better answered by studying canonical CRUD code and modeling it, rather than going through all of these gyrations about why your specific code does not work.

Comment: I know this answer is from 2014 but:
Regarding number 1, we live in a globalized world and this is the internet, even if the web page is in English and/or the creator of said page is an English speaker person, like it or not, a lot of people from different nationalities come here to ask for aid with the tools they have in regards of spelling.

So what Im trying to say is, people should learn English of course! but others should learn that English is not the only language out there, even if it is a really good proxy language.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. There are a vast number of people with enough reputation to downvote. They are members of a crowd. One of them may object to JPA in principle, or the rate at which you used the letter 'e'.

You should not stress or worry about a single downvote. You will get some on this site. If you get the answer you need, you should feel successful with this question.

Comment: I agree with you, but what if the question get downvoted before getting answers? People can look at the vote and skip the question, so it's not the "number" that's worrying me but how to write good questions, if someone vote -1 because he hate jpa, people can consider that vote unuseful and still be interested in question.