# Suggestion for questions that need help with English

Tags: feature-request, english

SO is clearly in English but not all people who contribute or want to contribute are native speakers.

What if a new state (of a question) was created so that people could check on the basis of the questions quality before made public and edits could be made in that context rather than the overall quality of the question? Maybe like next to the "Post Your Question" there is an option that says - "post and review for English". Other users could moderate based with that context rather than overall quality of a public question.

Comment: All you have to do to handle this is comment and edit. Help that user out- If they're a non-native speaker, they are probably fine with learning and will appreciate the help. Comments can always be cleaned up when you're done.

Comment: usually they are downvoted and closed in the current SO - the premise of this would be to have a private queue if the person asking the question wanted it. The fact that it came of out of this queue would be private so a fully opt-in scenario.

Comment: Even if they're closed, they can be reopened. If the question is on-topic and all that's wrong is bad English, edit and comment and help. If it's closed, it can be reopened once it's fixed. I've edited a couple of downvoted questions to help with English fixes and watched them get upvotes after they were fixed. So I don't see how another queue would help. _Especially_ mods only- The mods are busy enough.

Comment: prob wouldn't have to be mod-only (edited question to reflect)

Comment: Better- I still don't see how it'd be that big an improvement, however.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'that big an improvement' means. I think regarding the overall quality of SO, it would be a subtle improvement and also a sign that people who aren't native speakers are welcome. Also, probably based upon demographics, every English-speaking developer knows about SO which is probably less true of non-native speakers.

Comment: It'd definately be helpful...there were atleast three SQL questions this morning that were basically lost in translation and had to be closed as they couldn't be understood.  Almost a "I need help wording my question" queue.

Comment: It'd be helpful if people would make the effort to talk to the user and understand their question, then edit accordingly as well. The question can be closed in the meantime, that's fine. Closing a question is meant to give the OP a chance to fix it, anyway.

Comment: if you think downvoting / closing a question is the RIGHT way to handle this, I think that's a horrible experience for a new user. Re new-language site, SO is strong because of all the users - different language sites make sense for peopl. Finally, SO currently has too many of these types of questions and, to be honest, I don't want to read them.

Comment: @timpone I never said _I_ would downvote them- I would rather help first and if they refuse the help downvote. But other people will downvote and vote to close, and you cannot stop them from doing so. Is it right? No. Does it leave a bad impression? Yes. But if you take the time to help the user through that, that can change the impression a bit.

Comment: And if you don't want to read the questions, then don't. Just leave the question- Don't downvote or close vote if you feel that's wrong, but notice the bad English and leave. (I honestly hadn't considered downvoting this proposal until that comment- If you want to help them, pushing it off on others through a review is not the way to do it.)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue).

Comment: thx Will - hadn't seen that - definitely related but I would rather see it where the user doesn't have to identify themselves as needing help; probably would also think that these edits should be private. Perhaps a bit shameful / less desirable for developers where the highest praise is `he/she is really smart`. Maybe people could anonymously post questions to this section? But have to be signed-in to prevent any form of abuse.

Comment: @kendra not sure what comment you're talking about re your downvote; it's fine if you don't like the idea but the reality is that the questions get downvoted and closed which is a bad experience for a new user.

Comment: wierd all the unexplained downvotes....

Comment: I've seen lots of questions by non-native speakers that just need a little bit of help to make it clearer.  But I've also run into questions where it's rather clear the asker has made zero effort to make himself understood.  Those are the questions that should (and will) get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 4):

We already have a system in place for this: Edits and comments.

If you see a post that is on-topic, and just needs help with English, comment and make sure you understand what the user is asking (if it's unclear) then edit to help with with the English and phrasing.

Yes, they may get downvoted and closed in the meantime. Probably will, even. But closed questions *can* be reopened.

On top of that, you'll be showing the user, if they're new, that the site isn't all bad, and that people are willing to help. It would easily show that they can belong at Stack Overflow so long as they make an effort and are willing to learn.

Comment: And if it gets too much of a problem, that's why we have [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). The [Portuguese site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) came out of that, and there are other languages on the way.

Comment: I completely forgot about the different-language proposals. That's another way we're dealing with this.

Comment: @kendra - I agree with you that we have a system in place that works for a lot of scenario's, but I strongly disagree that this system works for this scenario in particular.  Step 1 clarify question, step 2 answer question...most of us expect the question to already be at step2 by the time it's posted, and downvote if it isn't...I can't imagine being hit with a series of negatives because you are struggling to clarify your question with english would feel good

Comment: @Twelfth I was looking for an example, but I comment so much here on Meta- My point is that yes, people expect that. People _also_ seem to expect that the asker is a native speaker and if their English is bad it's laziness. I've helped at least one person with this, and I'm pretty sure more, through edits. Granted, the ones I did were mostly clear about the problem, but the English was bad. At the same time, I'm still a newish programmer so I try not to edit questions that need clarified. No, it wouldn't feel good. But that's why someone should comment and help.

Comment: [Here's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269087/how-to-know-why-a-question-is-downvoted) the example I was looking for. User was negative when I went to the question. His question and answer are both positive now. (Note that I wasn't the only editor of the question; There were spots I myself missed, but it was still improved.)

Comment: that's actually also a good example of what's wrong with the current system; a user confused about why his question is being downvoted (when it creates the impression it is a poor question).